# Python Plotly Sunburst Coloring

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory

I have the following code to generate a sunburst plot using plotly in Google colab.

```
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_single_color_sunburst(person, color):
    color_hex = "#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}".format(int(color[0]*255), int(color[1]*255), int(color[2]*255))
    
    # Set everything to grey initially
    sample_df['color'] = 'grey'
    
    if person != 'all_greyscale':
        # Get the B values associated with the current person
        Bs = sample_df[sample_df[person].str.strip() == '1']['B'].tolist()
        
        # Color those specific B values
        sample_df.loc[sample_df['B'].isin(Bs), 'color'] = color_hex
        
        # Identify the unique A values for those specific B values
        As = sample_df[sample_df['B'].isin(Bs)]['A'].unique()
        
        # Color only those specific A entries
        for A in As:
            sample_df.loc[(sample_df['A'] == A) & (sample_df['B'] == ''), 'color'] = color_hex

    # Create the sunburst diagram with a fixed color mapping
    fig = px.sunburst(sample_df,
                      path=['A', 'B'],
                      color='color',
                      color_discrete_map={'grey': 'grey', color_hex: color_hex},
                      title=f'Sunburst highlighting {person}')
    
    # Remove the temporary 'color' column
    sample_df.drop('color', axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    return fig

def get_color_for_person(person_name):
    # Map each unique name to a unique number between 0 and 1
    unique_names = sample_df.columns[2:].tolist()  # Assuming the person columns start at index 2
    num_people = len(unique_names)
    name_mapping = {name: idx/num_people for idx, name in enumerate(unique_names)}
    
    # Get the color for the person using the viridis colormap
    colormap = plt.cm.viridis
    return colormap(name_mapping[person_name])

import pandas as pd

# Creating a new sample dataset
data = {
    'A': ['Dolor', 'Dolor', 'Sit', 'Sit', 'Amet', 'Amet'],
    'B': ['', 'Consectetur', 'Adipiscing', '', 'Elit', 'Sed'],
    'Jessica Smith': ['', '1', '', '1', '1', ''],
    'Thomas Brown': ['1', '', '1', '', '', '1'],
}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Generate a sunburst for 'Jessica Smith' for debugging
fig = generate_single_color_sunburst('Jessica Smith', get_color_for_person('Jessica Smith'))
fig.show()
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

The problem is that I want "Amet" and "Sit" to be purple, too. In other words, when any B is colored in, I want the corresponding A to also be colored in. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when any B is colored in, I want the corresponding A to also be colored in": so this works perfectly when all of the Bs are colored.

But in the case of "Amet" or "Sit" (in your example), when only one of the Bs are colored, then the parent ("A" in the example) in the hierarchical tree strucutre/sunburst chart will have that color column as `'?'` (see image below).

I assume this happens because it can't aggregate the two different color values .

[image]

One workaround is to explicitly add a key for that case in your color_discrete_map like this:

```
    color_discrete_map={'grey': 'grey', color_hex: color_hex,'(?)': color_hex}
    fig = px.sunburst(sample_df,
                      path=['A', 'B'],
                      color='color',
                      color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map,
                      title=f'Sunburst highlighting {person}')
```

Hope this helps.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah, obvious in retrospect. Thank  you.